# Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com'

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I get this error after making my first request:

> Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per
> minute' of service 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com'

**How can I be over my quota after my first request?**

```
if(File.Exists(ApplicationVariables.CertPath)) { 
                    GoogleCredential credential;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(ApplicationVariables.CertPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage");
                    }

                    // Create the service.
                    var service = new MyBusinessAccountManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                        {
                            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                            ApplicationName = "Google Reviews Downloader",
                        });

                    //var bookshelves = await service.Mylibrary.Bookshelves.List().ExecuteAsync();
                    var accounts = await service.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine("accounts:" + accounts);

                }
```

Comment: whoever voted this down and to close...why?  this is a legitimate question.  I see other similar threads on SO, but I don't see any matching my situation exactly.

Comment: People like to downvote and close questions that they don't understand.   I agree your question is legitimate.

Comment: @s15199d were you able to resolve using the Quota request form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would depend entirely on how much quota you have currently.

When you enable the `My Business Account Management API` in Google developer console. THe default quota is 0

[image]

I would suggest that you try and add additional quota.

[image]

Your going to have to click the quota page link and dig around in there a while until you figure out how to increase the quota, they changed it recently, you may have to apply for quota im not sure with this api.

I have tried and im not any wiser as to how to request quota or increase the quota.  I wonder if this is one of the APIs that you need special permission to access.   How you get that permission im not sure but im going to do a bit of digging.

Comment: Great thought @DalmTo, I just checked that and when you attempt to click the pencil  it says "This limit may not be edited".

Comment: yeah click the link at the top of the page.

Comment: Found it!  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdoCw8P5JJsJ-taCH2i8w8B69sGsZfoRhacQOe7FTWArWZ-SQ/viewform

Comment: There's a link to the form to request quota here https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest